# How to write Jmeter script for AWS cognito login

Tags: jmeter, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create jmeter script for login in to iphone native app. App is using cognito to authenticate the user.
As response of first page of app I am getting SALT and Secret block.
I am passing this secret block in and other required parameters in next request, however I got error message as "User name or password is in correct".

Did anyone worked successfully on similar things which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) page:

> **Social and enterprise identity federation**
>
> With Amazon Cognito, your users can sign in through social identity providers such as Google, Facebook, and [Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/login-with-amazon), and through enterprise identity providers such as [Microsoft Active Directory](https://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/active-directory/) via [SAML](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/saml/).
>
> **Standards-based authentication**
>
> Amazon Cognito User Pools is a standards-based Identity Provider and supports identity and access management standards, such as Oauth 2.0, [SAML 2.0](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/saml/), and OpenID Connect.

You will not be able to record and replay none of the mentioned protocols, depending on underlying identity provider mechanism you will either need to apply advanced correlation or a way to provide the required [Bearer Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

So you need to identify which identity mechanism is used under the hood and amend your JMeter test accordingly.

Reference material:

- [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites-with-jm)
- [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter)
- [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am using Cognito User Pools
I have set the correlation which is available in response. However I am not getting Bearer Token which is a problem